# How to read T-SQL time statistics?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, execution-plan

I have a simple stored procedure as an example, which reads a table with 3 rows.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE demo_procedure
AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM my_table
    END
```

When I run it with time statistics on:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
GO
exec demo_procedure
GO
```

I get:

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 2 ms.

(3 rows affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 3 ms.
```

How should I read this data? Does the stored procedure takes 2 ms, 3 ms or 5 ms?

Comment: Check out this link also which helps parse the output to a more readable format https://statisticsparser.com

Answer (score 3):

Parse and compile is the time it takes to validate syntax and object validity, then compile an execution plan. Elapsed time is how long it takes the query to execute and finish returning rows to the client (SSMS). If you're returning a lot of rows, the query itself may be done long before rows are done rendering in SSMS.